# Getting IPMI SMB (I2C SMBus SSIF) to work on kernel 3.2

Tags: debian, intel, ipmi, bmc, dmidecode

I've got one old server into my hands, and I'm trying to get IPMI to work.

Server board is **SE7520JR2** (`SE7520JR22S, SE7520JR22.86B.P.08.10.0081.051820051126`)

```
$ dmidecode -t 38
# dmidecode 2.11
SMBIOS 2.3 present.

Handle 0x0038, DMI type 38, 18 bytes
IPMI Device Information
        Interface Type: SSIF (SMBus System Interface)
        Specification Version: 1.5
        I2C Slave Address: 0x10
        NV Storage Device: Not Present
        Base Address: 0x42 (SMBus)
```

I've got I2C port working via

```
$ modprobe i2c-i801
$ modprobe i2c-dev
$ ls -lsa /dev/i2c-0
0 crw-rw---T 1 root i2c 89, 0 Apr 18 01:55 /dev/i2c-0
```

And I've also got the BMC info

```
$ bmc-info -D ssif --disable-auto-probe --driver-address=0x42 --driver-device=/dev/i2c-0 
Device ID             : 32
Device Revision       : 1
Device SDRs           : supported
Firmware Revision     : 2.40
Device Available      : yes (normal operation)
IPMI Version          : 1.5
Sensor Device         : supported
SDR Repository Device : supported
SEL Device            : supported
FRU Inventory Device  : supported
IPMB Event Receiver   : supported
IPMB Event Generator  : unsupported
Bridge                : unsupported
Chassis Device        : supported
Manufacturer ID       : Intel Corporation (343)
Product ID            : 17169
```

Also `ipmi-chassis-config` output seems to be not complete

```
$ ipmi-chassis-config -D ssif --disable-auto-probe --driver-address=0x42 --driver-device=/dev/i2c-0 --checkout 
#
# Section Chassis_Front_Panel_Buttons Comments 
#
# The following configuration options are for enabling or disabling button 
# functionality on the chassis. Button may refer to a pushbutton, switch, or 
# other front panel control built into the system chassis. 
#
# The value of the below may not be able to be checked out. Therefore we 
# recommend the user configure all four fields rather than a subset of them, 
# otherwise some assumptions on configure may be made. 
#
Section Chassis_Front_Panel_Buttons
$
```

The problem is that `ipmi_smb` kernel driver is not present since kernel release 2.6.35/36, and `ipmi_si`is not suitable for **SSIF**/**I2C** configuration (as far as I understand modinfo).

Thus any tool like `ipmitool` will fail (`Could not open device at /dev/ipmi0 or /dev/ipmi/0 or /dev/ipmidev/0: No such file or directory`)

Is there any support for SSIF IPMI devices in later kernels, or can it be somehow added?
I'm running Debian 7.4 (`3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.54-2 x86_64 GNU/Linux`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think so. I have the same old hardware here and I'm also stuck at kernel 2.6.35. It seems that the patch was not ported for newer kernel releases :/

Comment: You could port it yourself! :D

Comment: @TomO'Connor well if you're able to port the patch for newer kernels, go for it, i have no such experience yet.